# getting an object by id in a GSP file

Tags: grails, gsp

Part of my domain model has `Conversation` which has many `ChatMessage`s

In my index.gsp I have the following :

```
<g:each in="${allConversations}" var="conversation">
        ${conversation.chatMessages}
    </g:each>
```

to display all conversations of a particular user, which outputs the chat messages as

```
[hi, how are you][another convo, hi again]
```

which is the correct results.  But I only want to get the first message of each conversation.  I have tried

```
${conversation.chatMessages[0]}
```

and

```
${conversation.chatMessages.get(0)}
```

but to no avail.  What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Is the `chatMessages` property of your `Conversation` class declared as a List? If so then either form should work, but if it's just a `hasMany` with no explicit List declaration then it's a Set, which you can't index into by number.

Comment: yea its part of a hasMany as I was having problems persisting an arraylist to the DB, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to refer to individual messages within the conversation by *index* then you need to declare the association as a List:

```
class Conversation {
  static hasMany = [chatMessages: ChatMessage]

  List chatMessages

  // constraints, mapping, other properties...
}
```

If you have only the `hasMany` without the `List chatMessages` then the association will be mapped as a Set rather than a List, which lets you iterate but not access by index.

See [sets, lists and maps](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) in the grails docs for full details.

Comment: thanks I understand that now.  My domain model is producing a DB error when using this however due to bad architecture on my side, but I will continue to get this working.  In the meantime I am am using `${conversation.chatMessages.toArray[0]}` in my GSP file until I get this working properly.  Thanks for your solution

Comment: @andymccullough mapping an association as a `List` requires an extra not-null column in the relevant database table (to store the index number of each entry), so you may have to drop and re-create your DB (or work out the SQL to add the new column as nullable, fill in the right values, then switch it to not-null...).  The trouble with using a default `Set` association as you are now is that it doesn't have any intrinsic order, i.e. the message that you get out as `[0]` won't necessarily always be the same from call to call.